# Display problem when changing the language

Tags: css, vuejs3

Good afternoon, the problem is as follows there is a drop-down window for choosing the language of the site, when changing all the flags when choosing behave as required, but when choosing French, it falls down in the range 1021-1199. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hX8uh.png)  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MrEw.png)

I tried to reisht through @meadia, but then these changes are already applied to those flags that behaved corecto and they climb up accordingly. Tell me what is the reason that only one flag falls down, and how to fix it?
I will add my code below

```
<template>
  <div
    class="country_changer clickable-item"
    :class="{ opened: isMenuOpened }"
  >
    <div ref="ignoreElRef" class="country_changer_icon main-navigation-button" @click.stop.prevent="handleClick">
      <nuxt-img
        preload
        :src="`/images/main/flags/${ currentLocation?.countryCode ? currentLocation.countryCode.toLowerCase() : 'de' }.svg`"
        width="52"
        height="52"
        :title="`${currentLocation?.countryName}`"
        :alt="`${currentLocation?.countryName}`"
      />
    </div>
    <div ref="countriesList" class="countries">
      <div class="container">
        <ul class="row">
          <template v-for="item in localeList?.data">
            <li v-if="item.location_enabled" :key="item.location_id" class="col-md-3 col-sm6 col-xs-6">
              <a
                href="#"
                :title="`${item.country.nm_country_name} / ${item.language.nm_language_name}`"
                @click.prevent="onLocationChange(item)"
              >
                <nuxt-img
                  preload
                  :src="`/images/main/flags/${item.location_country}.svg`"
                  width="40"
                  height="40"
                  :title="`${item.country.nm_country_name} - ${item.language.nm_language_name}`"
                  :alt="`${item.country.nm_country_name} / ${item.language.nm_language_name}`"
                  class="d-inline"
                />
                <span><strong>{{ item.country.nm_country_name }}</strong><br>{{ item.language.nm_language_name }}</span>
                <div class="clear" />
              </a>
            </li>
          </template>
        </ul>
        <div class="clear" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { toRef, useContext } from '@nuxtjs/composition-api'
import Vue, { ref } from 'vue'
import { onClickOutside } from '@vueuse/core'
import useError from '~/compositions/useError'
import useLocale from '~/compositions/useLocale'
import { LocationDto } from '~/types/locales'
import useCart from '~/compositions/useCart'

export default Vue.extend({
  setup () {
    const { app } = useContext()
    const { state, getLocaleList, setCurrentLocation } = useLocale()
    const { changeCurrency } = useCart()
    const { data: localeList, error, isValidating, mutate } = getLocaleList()

    const isMenuOpened = ref(false)
    const ignoreElRef = ref()
    const onLocationChange = async (location: LocationDto) => {
      isMenuOpened.value = false
      setCurrentLocation({
        countryCode: location.location_country,
        countryName: `${location.country.nm_country_name} / ${location.language.nm_language_name}`,
        currentCurrency: location.location_currency,
        currentLanguage: location.location_language,
        currentCurrencyFormat: `${location.location_language}-${location.location_country.toUpperCase()}`
      })
      try {
        await changeCurrency(location.location_currency, false)
      } catch (error) {
        useError().handleError(error, (errors) => {
          Vue.$toast.error(errors.currency_id[0])
        })
      }
      if (app.router) {
        const currentRoute = app.router.currentRoute.fullPath
        const currentI18nLocale = app.i18n.locale
        if (currentRoute.startsWith(`/${currentI18nLocale}`)) {
          const newPath = currentRoute?.replace(`/${currentI18nLocale}`, `/${location.location_language}`)
          app.router.push(newPath)
        } else {
          app.router.push(`/${location.location_language}${currentRoute}`)
        }
      }
    }

    const countriesList = ref(null)
    onClickOutside(countriesList, () => {
      isMenuOpened.value = false
    }, { ignore: [ignoreElRef, countriesList] })
    const handleClick = () => {
      isMenuOpened.value = !isMenuOpened.value
    }
    return {
      countriesList,
      currentLocation: toRef(state, 'currentLocation'),
      localeList,
      isValidating,
      error,
      mutate,
      onLocationChange,
      isMenuOpened,
      ignoreElRef,
      handleClick
    }
  }
})
</script>

<style scoped>
.col-xs-6 {
  width: 50%;
}
</style>

<style scoped>
#top_menu .country_changer div.countries {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #fff;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 20px;
    top: 118px;
}

#top_menu .country_changer.opened div.countries {
    height: auto;
    padding: 20px 20px;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 4px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 10%);
    z-index: 2;
}

#top_menu .country_changer {
  /* 3 */
  float: right;
  
}

#main_navigation .country_changer_icon {
  /* 2 */
  position: relative;
  bottom: 75px;
 
}
#navigation.navig-fixed .country_changer {
  display: none;
}

#top_menu .country_changer .country_changer_icon img {
/* 1 */
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  transform: scaleX(.888) scaleY(1.111);
  
}

#top_menu .country_changer ul li {
  text-align: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}
#top_menu .country_changer ul li:hover {
  border: 1px solid #f18a00;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: #F6F6F6;
}

#top_menu .country_changer ul li a {
    padding: 14px 0;
    min-height: 20px;
    color: #000;
}
#top_menu .country_changer li a {
    display: block;
}

#top_menu .country_changer ul li a img {
    margin-right: 15px;
    float: left;
    width: 40px;
}

#top_menu .country_changer ul li a span {
    float: left;
}


@media (max-width: 991px) {
  #main_navigation .country_changer_icon {
    bottom: 2px;
  }

  #top_menu .country_changer div.countries {
    top: 192px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 770px){
  #top_menu .country_changer ul li, #top_menu .countries .container {
    padding: 0;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 650px) {
  #top_menu .country_changer div.countries {
    top: 45px;
  }
  #main_navigation .country_changer_icon {
    background-color: #ffffff00;
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 50px;
    top: 0px;
    right: 170px;
    height: 50px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px){
  #navigation .country_changer .country_changer_icon {
    top: 0px
  }

  #navigation.navig-fixed .country_changer .country_changer_icon
  {
    top: -45px;
  }
  #navigation.navig-fixed .country_changer {
    display: initial;
  }
  #top_menu .country_changer ul li a {
    padding: 7px 0;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 400px) {
  #main_navigation .country_changer_icon {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    top: 5px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {

  #top_registration .account .login.main-navigation-button,
  #main_navigation .main-navigation-button:not(.website_search_icon) {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 15px 0 2.5px 2.5px;
  }
  #main_navigation .country_changer  .country_changer_icon {
    top: 0px;
    right: 125px;
  }
  #website_search .website_search_input input{
    padding-right: 40px
  }
}
</style>
```